# How do I match the following Ruby gsub in Python's re?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following function in Ruby that indents a string by a user-defined number of spaces at each new line.

```
def reindent(str, numIndent)
    return str.gsub(/(.)^/m) { |m| $1 + ("    " * numIndent) }
end
```

How would I mimic this function in Python using re?

I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
def reindent(line, numIndent):
  return re.sub(r'(.)^', r'\1' + '    ' * numIndent, line, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: I take it your goal is to *not* indent the very first line, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Well, then check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that Matz has chosen to confuse everybody by renaming the `/s` modifier (`SINGLELINE` or  `DOTALL`) as it's used in all other regex flavors to Ruby's `/m` (`MULTILINE`) modifier (which deals with whether newlines are treated as "any character" or not by the `.` token).

Conversely, what other flavors do call the `/m` or `MULTILINE` modifier (which determines whether `^` and `$` match at the start/end of lines instead of just the start/end of the entire string) doesn't exist at all in Ruby. Those anchors *always*  match at the start/end of lines.

So, to translate your code from Ruby into Python, you need to do

```
def reindent(line, numIndent):
    return re.sub(r'(.)^', r'\1' + '    ' * numIndent, line, flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

If your goal is to indent all lines but the first one (which is what this is doing), you can simplify the regex:

```
def reindent(line, numIndent):
    return re.sub(r'(?<!\A)^', '    ' * numIndent, line, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Result:

```
>>> s = "The following lines\nare indented,\naren't they?"
>>> print(reindent(s,1))
The following lines
    are indented,
    aren't they?
```

Comment: _Conversely, what other flavors do call the /m ... doesn't exist at all in Ruby. Those anchors always match at the start/end of lines._ Wrong. Regexp without a modifier behaves exactly as perl's regexp with /m. [See appropriate documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes)

Comment: @DavidUnric: OK, how do you make `^` and `$` match *only* the start and end of the entire string in Ruby? You can't. There is no modifier in Ruby that would allow you to change this behaviour. It's like Perl's `/m` is stuck in the "On" position.

Comment: What is the difference between the first two functions? I tried them both, and they seem to have the same behavior.

Comment: @idealistikz: Their behaviour is identical, but the second is more efficient because it doesn't need to replace all the `\n`s with themselves. It's about a 10 % performance gain (`timeit.timeit()` told me so).

Answer (score 0):

Use a reversed form instead:

```
import re
def reindent(line, numIndent):
  return re.sub(r'^(.*)', '    ' * numIndent + r'\1', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(reindent("abcdefghijkl\nmnopqrstu", 1))
```

Output:

```
    abcdefghijkl
    mnopqrstu
```

Comment: First, the result differs from the OP's initial regex where the first line is left unindented. Second, why match the entire line and later replace it with itself? There's no need for `.*` (there almost never is...)

Comment: If the OP really intended that then you're correct. And a solution is a solution no matter how.